# Split the column and find min , max and avg value in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Let consider i have below data

```
Name        Fee
Student1    Fee paid : 100rs 
Student2    Fee paid : 500rs
Student3    Fee paid : 200rs
```

I need to select **max ,min and avg** value of Fee column which need to split up by : and rs delimiter

For Example Here 
Result is

```
Min     Max     Avg
100     500     250
```

Comment: what has the *Name* column to do with this question?

Comment: In the future, you should really not store data like this.  Store numeric data in its own numeric column.  Doing a string split to get anything meaningful out of a column is not really a good design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for that:

```
select min(fee_num), max(fee_num), avg(fee_num)
from (
        select to_number(regexp_substr(fee, ':\s*(\d+)\s*rs', 1, 1, null, 1)) fee_num
        from mytable
     )
```

The 6<sup>th</sup> argument of [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm) (available since Oracle 11g) allows you to return only the text matched by the capture group (i.e. `\d+` in this case).

The regular expression requires a `:` to be optionally followed by white-space (`\s*`), then to have some digit(s) (`\d+`), again followed by optional white space, with `rs` following that.

Note that retrieving amounts from text columns defeats any advantage you could have from a structured database: indexes on that column won't be used, and the extraction with regular expressions comes with an overhead.

In normalised relational database design, a field contains atomic data only, not anything else. So in this case the `fee` column should contain the amount only and be of a numerical data type. Any other information you need to know about the fee should be stored in different column(s).